# Let $ $ be a square matrix of order $$ such that $A^2=A$ Prove that every $∈\mathbb R^n$ can be decomposed as $ =_1+_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, idempotents

> Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$ such that $A^2 = A$. Prove that every $v \in \Bbb R^n$ can be decomposed as $v = v_1 +v_2$, where $v_1$ is in the null space of $A$ and $v_2$ is in the column space of $A$.

The decomposition is unique. How do we go about proving this?

Comment: I edited the body.  Please edit the title.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Let us denote the null space of $A$ by $N(A)$ and the column space of $A$ by $C(A).$ Show that $C(A)=N(I-A)$ and $ \mathbb R^n= N(A) \oplus C(A).$

Answer (score 1):

A vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n $ can be written uniquely as

$ v = v - A v + A v = (I - A) v + A v = v_1 + v_2 \hspace{15pt} (1) $

Now since $A^2 = A$ , then $ A - A^2 = A (I - A) = 0 $

$A v_1 = A (I - A) v = 0 $, so $v_1$ is in the null space of $A$

and $v_2 = A v $ so $v_2$ is in the column space of $A$.

Now I show that if $x$ is the null space then it cannot be in the column space unless $x = 0$, thus proving that the null space of $A$ and the columns space are disjoint.

Let $x$ be in the null space of $A$, then

$ A x = 0 $,

If $x$ is the column space of $A$ then, there exists a vector $y$ such that

$ x = A y $

Now pre-multiply both sides by $A$,

$ A x = A^2 y = A y$

But $A x = 0 $ by our assumption, then

$ A y = 0 $

Therefore,

$ x = 0 $

This proves that the null space of $A$ and its column space are disjoint.

Now suppose vector $v = u_1 + u_2$ where $u_1 $ is in the null space and $u_2$ is in the column space then

$ v = v_1 + v_2 = u_1 + u_2 $

where now we have $v_1, u_1$ are in the null space, and $v_2 , u_2$ are the column space.  Then we can write

$ u_1 = v_1 + x $  implying that $u_2 = v_2 - x $

Since $u_1$ and $v_1$ are in the null space then $x$ is in the null space, and since $u_2$ and $v_2$ are in the column space then $x$ is also in the column space, thus $x$ is in both the null space and the column space, so $x$ must be the zero vector $0$.  Hence $u_1 = v_1$ and $u_2 = v_2$

Thus the decomposition of a vector $v$ given above is unique.

Thanks to a comment by @Weltschmerz in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6235/what-is-the-best-way-to-show-an-idempotent-matrix-whose-nullspace-and-range-are) for the decomposition that I based my answer on.